# Implementing photoshop glass distortion filter

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, distortion

I have a homework where I need to implement a glass distortion filter using OpenGL. Basically what I am allowed to do is read a pixel from one image and write it to another one (teacher's limitations).

The result of the filter should be something like this:

[image: Filter]

Is there any tutorial or code explaining how that works?

Comment: Hi I would ask this in gamedev.

Comment: But it is not for a game it is just to apply the filter on a image... honestly i do not know where to post that question, and because i dont have a clue how to implement it i asked here :(

Comment: Do a gaussian blur and then blend some noise on top, or perhaps shift/smear the pixels by some random offset. Looks like it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try displacement noise, something like:
new_pic(x,y) = old_pic( x+dx(x,y), y+dy(x,y) )
where dx and dy some bounded smooth functions, for example:
dx(x,y)= 0
dy(x,y)= sin(y)*sin(x)

p.s. After getting the main idea, you will probably want better displacement functions, I recomend Perlin noise, here's Ken Perlin's great article:
http://www.noisemachine.com/talk1/